# Haskell equivalent of C++ typed pair

Tags: c++, haskell

I'm think of converting following C++ code into Haskell

```
#include <utility>

template<typename Pair>
struct inv_pair
{
    typedef std::pair<
        typename Pair::second_type, 
        typename Pair::first_type
    > type;
};
```

The inv_pair basically invert pair's first_type and second_type. It can be used as follows

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> pair_t1;    
typedef inv_pair<pair_t1>::type inv_par_t1; 
// of type std::pair<std::string, int>
```

Haskell

```
data Pair' = Pair' Int String
-- then?
```

Maybe it's not an useful pattern. Still curious and willing to learn.

Comment: I thought this question was about how to define a type-level function (from types to types) such that given the type `(a,b)` it would produce the type `(b,a)`. This is what the C++ code seem to do, in my eyes. However, most answers below are about how to swapping pair _values_, à la `Data.Tuple.swap`. Was that the intended meaning?

Comment: @chi I do like to know a type-level way. The one Jefffrey provided (as of his side note) operate type constructor which is almost there. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible Haskell translation of the following C++ type hackery

```
template<typename Pair>
struct inv_pair
{
    typedef std::pair<
        typename Pair::second_type, 
        typename Pair::first_type
    > type;
};

typedef std::pair<int, std::string> pair_t1;
typedef inv_pair<pair_t1>::type inv_pair_t1;
```

could be the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family Swap t 
type instance Swap (a,b) = (b,a)

type Pair_t1     = (Int, String)
type Inv_Pair_t1 = Swap Pair_t1
```

I am not so sure this would be useful in practice, though.

Answer (score 8):

In [`Data.Tuple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html) there's already a function called `swap` which does what you need. It's type is:

```
swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
```

As an example the following:

```
import Data.Tuple

tuple :: (Int, String)
tuple = (1, "OK")

main = putStr $ (fst . swap) tuple
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25e7d05190e1f804)

will print `OK`.

---

On a side note, the data constructor for pairs is `(,)` which can be called (thanks to syntactic sugar) as:

```
(a, b)
```

instead of:

```
(,) a b
```

So you could also flip the data constructor for pairs. For example:

```
flip (,)
```

will produce a data constructor with reversed arguments. So that:

```
reversedTuple :: b -> a -> (a, b)
reversedTuple = flip (,)

main = putStr $ fst $ reversedTuple "First" "Second"
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5107b46762fb094)

will print `Second`.

Comment: I do not know about the down vote, but your live demo is not printing anything out other then "runghc main.cpp
OK".

Comment: Didn't vote anyone yet. I intend to use type constructor for the inverted tuple(pair). Is that possible?

Comment: @Davorak, that is like a *command line*. It's often used to compile Haskell code. `runghc` is the command sent to run the file and `main.cpp` is the file used, in that case. `OK` is the expected output.

Comment: @Jefffrey I guess user-defined `data Pair a b` example would be a nice complement to your answer.

Comment: @CrazyFIZRUK, thanks. I've added a note on the pair type constructor.

Comment: @CrazyFIZRUK Exactly what I'd like to know!

Comment: @Jefffrey - The issue I had was that I was not expecting to have to hit edit then run/compile to see the result of the program.

Comment: @Davorak, you don't have to. The programs output is cached already where the link points to. For example if you go [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25e7d05190e1f804) you see `runghc main.cpp
OK`, which is the command + output of the program.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell has built-in tuples. For example `(3, "foo")` has type `(Int, String)`.

Creating the "inverted" pair is easy. For example the following function swaps the two entries of a pair:

```
swap (x, y) = (y, x)
```

and its type can be written down as

```
swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
```